# Bluetooth version for mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, battery-life, wireless-mouse

What new features are exposed in newer versions of the Bluetooth standard that improve such things as power consumption and latency specifically in the use case of a Bluetooth mouse? For instance, does a BT5.2 link use less mouse battery and increase polling rate versus a BT3.0 connection? If a mouse has the option of both link types, what extra features does BT5.2 add versus BT3.0 if both devices support it?

Comment: I use a Logitech M535 Bluetooth Mouse on my ThinkPad computer and it works a treat. I specify this mouse for clients and it works great for them. Batteries last 3 or 4 months under heavy and constant use; 6 months under normal use. Totally stable and no lag in operation.  Excellent.

Comment: Higher bluetooth specs will have advantages over lower specs, such as higher speed, better battery and optional features, such as battery indicators, etc. But that doesn't mean you really need a mouse with high spec. It is all down to personal preference and learning about what each BT version offers over the previous in comparison to your budget and needs.

Comment: I'm explicitly asking if the BT version matters for a mouse. How is that "opinionated"? And why does that require direct moderator intervention? What should I do to edit the question so that it is considered on topic?

Comment: The comment by LPChip above explains why it is opinion based. Any question where the "correct" answer is down to the the posters needs and budget is opinion based as only you can make the decision.

Comment: @DavidPostill I absolutely disagree with that comment. "such as higher speed, better battery and optional features, such as battery indicators, etc.": really? If that's the case then I would certainly want to learn which BT spec would introduce e.g. battery indicators or why I would need a "higher speed" for something like a mouse. Specific bluetooth versions may have different options, but how much battery power is saved using BT 5 compared with BT 3? How can I make a choice without even that kind of knowledge? If I give you a list of mice, do you have a "personal preference" for them?